# how to make an object array inside redis?

Tags: arrays, redis

I am trying to add a json object which is like

```
{"username":"krishna_Ayush", session_ids:["aabchdhddh", "dkddjsjsjsjs", "djkjdjffj"]}
```

Now my question is that how add this json document in my redis now my major concern is how add this data as far i read there i found many possible ways like

**1.** use `PUSH` method like this `rpush(["krishna_Ayush", "aabchdhddh", "dkddjsjsjsjs", "djkjdjffj"])`

**2.** Use `Hash` (I am not clear how to use this) `HMSET USERS user_name "krishna_Ayush" session_id ["aabchdhddh", "dkddjsjsjsjs", "djkjdjffj"]`

Now I don't know which should I use, I guess second one is better as it seems to be a more general way of adding this.

Actually my basic question is that **how to make an object array inside redis**

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use *hashes*. A *hash* is a *hash table* where keys are strings and values are also strings.

Your keys will be user names and your values JSON strings:

```
hset users krishna_Ayush '{\"username\":\"krishna_Ayush\", session_ids:[\"aabchdhddh\", \"dkddjsjsjsjs\", \"djkjdjffj\"]}'
```

This way, you'll be able to get users' info by their user name using for example `hget krishna_Ayush`.

> Actually my basic question is that how to make an object array inside
>   redis

Redis doesn't support the *object* concept. You just store info in different data structures: lists, sets, sorted sets, hashes... And what you call *object* should be stored as a regular serialization string like JSON, XML, MessagePack, BSON or whatever.

Comment: @amanverma It's because JSON part has quots inside (JSON property names...). I've escaped them... Check the updated code...